# NFS doesn't mount after username change

Tags: mount, nfs, automount

NFS was working fine and I had managed to mount my entire `/home/old_name` folder upon login/boot, however, after a username change (`sudo usermod new_name old_name`) and updating `/etc/fstab`, NFS no longer mounts `/home/new_name`. What has gone wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: NOTE: This is a question for the sake of answering it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what was happening was that I changed the username without changing the user/group IDs, which I thought would not interfere with NFS (which is true, and it didn't), however, I didn't realize that I also had to manually change the home folder. Therefore, the computer was automounting to `/home/new_user`, but I was being logged into a blank `/home/old_user` directory. Simply run the below command to change your home folder, and everything should work fine:

```
usermod -d /home/new_user new_user
```

Replacing `new_user` with your new username...in case that is not clear